# Implementing redirect in Redux middleware

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, react.js, redux

Let's say I have following action:

```
export function signIn(data) {
  return {
    type: USER_SIGN_IN,
    promise: api.post('/sign_in', data)
  }
}
```

and the following middleware:

```
export default function promiseMiddleware() {
  return next => action => {
    const { promise, type, ...rest } = action

    if (!promise) {
      return next(action)
    }

    const SUCCESS = `${type}_SUCCESS`
    const REQUEST = `${type}_REQUEST`
    const ERROR = `${type}_ERROR`

    next({ ...rest, type: REQUEST })

    return promise
      .then(res => {
        next({ ...rest, response: res.data, type: SUCCESS })
        return true
      })
      .catch(error => {
        next({ ...rest, response: error.response.data, type: ERROR })
        return false
      })
  }
}
```

This code is loosely based on https://github.com/reactGo/reactGo/

**But what if in `then` callback after calling `next` I want to make a redirect to another path?**

I did following. I passed redirect url through action:

```
export function signIn(data) {
  return {
    type: USER_SIGN_IN,
    promise: api.post('/sign_in', data),
    redirect: '/'
  }
}
```

and added another call of `next` method with `push` from `react-router-redux`:

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux'

export default function promiseMiddleware() {
  return next => action => {
    const { promise, type, redirect, ...rest } = action

    if (!promise) {
      return next(action)
    }

    const SUCCESS = `${type}_SUCCESS`
    const REQUEST = `${type}_REQUEST`
    const ERROR = `${type}_ERROR`

    next({ ...rest, type: REQUEST })

    return promise
      .then(res => {
        next({ ...rest, response: res.data, type: SUCCESS })
        next(push(redirect))
        return true
      })
      .catch(error => {
        next({ ...rest, response: error.response.data, type: ERROR })
        return false
      })
  }
}
```

It seems like it works, but I'm not sure if this is a good idea or if there are some pitfalls of multiple `next` calls and I shouldn't do like this? Or maybe I should use `dispatch` method which I can get from `promiseMiddleware` params instead of `next` for redirecting?

If there are some better approaches for implementing such redirects, please, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating your custom `promiseMiddleware` you could use the `redux-thunk` middleware which accepts a function as an action. And the function will be called with `dispatch` and `getStore` as parameters.

Imagine you would like to fetch some data.. and you want to do it as an action. like `dispatch(getPost(id))`

normally your actionCreator `getPost` would return the action object,

```
const getPost = (id) => {
  return {
    type: "FETCH_POST",
    id
  }
}
```

But when you use `redux-thunk` you can return a function:

```
const getPost = (postId) => {
  return dispatch => {
      // Now you can use dispatch inside this block, even for async calls..
      // Start fetching.. 
      dispatch({type: "START_LOADING_POST" }) // imagine this could change your state to {isLoading: true}

      http
       .get("from.somewhere.net/post/" + postId)
       .then((data) => dispatch({type: "POST_LOADED_SUCCESS", postId, data }))
       .catch((error) => dispatch(loadingPostFailed({postId, error})))
  }
}
```

I think you know how to apply the middleware to the store, so I skip it. Hope it makes it clear how you can extend your `actionCreators` with `redux-thunk` to functions and use them specially for **async** tasks, like promises or even with callback-based libraries.

Redux thunk was part of redux, but its now an own package, but also maintained by Dan Abramov, check out the repo: https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk

If you would like to save some time by writing every actionCreator by hand you could create an creator for the actionCreator :D sounds funny, but take a look at this:

```
const promiseActionCreator = type => {
   const
      start    = type + "_START",
      resolved = type + "_RESOLVED",
      failed   = type + "_FAILED";

   return (params) => (dispatch, getState) => {

      dispatch({type: start})

      http
          .get(params.url)
          .then(result => dispatch({type: resolved, result }))
          .catch(error => dispatch({type: failed, error }))
   }
}

// Now you can create/generate your special promise based actionCreator
const getPost = promiseActionCreator("POST_LOADER");
```

Comment: I got it, thanks, but there will be a lot of boilerplate and repeating code in actionCreators which I'd like to avoid and make my actions small and clean. That's why I were looking for better approach if it exists.

Comment: common which code will repeat that much? you have to create the promise, you have to call then / catch anyway..

Comment: This approach handles the promise inside the action, your approach is to create the promise and pass it via the action.., right?

Comment: In my approach for each actionCreator I create promise and pass it to the action with some additional params if needed (e.g. redirect path, flash message etc.), and then I don't have to write promise handlers in each actionCreator (since all of them will be pretty similar). Does it make sense?

Comment: Well, the function `getPost` is an action creator. I am creating the promise inside it with `http.get`, and I am handling the promise completely inside it too, and have much more control because I am in the context. When you pass your promise around, it will get completed and handled somewhere else, in a **generic function**. Yes you are saving some lines of code per action. but you will loose a lot of flexibility per action, or would end up with a bigger middleWare to handle all different cases.. this would bring more complexity instead of simplicity. IMO

Comment: OK, but what if I get 404 from API? Should I handle request fail in every actionCreator, check its status and redirect to 404 page? I think such things definitely should be handled somewhere in one single place...

Comment: True, for example I have created a middleWare  which redirect the user to the login page if I the action contains: `{error: {msg: "Not Authenticated"}}` but I still dispatch the action in the actionCreator like `.catch(error => dispatch(loadingPostFailed(error) ))` And it doesn't matter which actionCreator was called, I just react on a single piece on data, like error: "Not Authenticated".. this statement is clear and does not have other cases, just redirect to login..

Comment: @ktaras check out my last edit, think about this, you could create a reducer the same way.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

In the case that you want to stop dispatching process and start over with new action (redirecting action), it's ok to use `dispatch(action)` instead of `next(action)`. Because when you call `dispatch(action)`, it will open a new cycle for middlewares.

That means action will be handled from the very first middleware towards that I think it should be. But carefully because when you call `dispatch(action)` inside a middleware, that can lead to infinitive loop on dispatch process. I refer you to read [this article](https://medium.com/@tamnvt1/redux-api-applymiddleware-acf1977e0a73) to understand more about Redux middleware.